# same [not-fixed] width of same column in multiple tables in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, xhtml

I have several tables on the same page, each with the same number of columns.  I want the first column in all the tables to have the same width, likewise for the second, etc.  I do not want to specify a fixed width (e.g., 100px), but rather let the browser calculate it.  How can I accomplish this in HTML/XHTML/CSS/js?

Comment: I can almost guarantee what the browser would do (if it could do what you're asking) will *not* be what you want it to look like. Why can't you do fixed width?

Comment: If I do it all in one table, it looks like what I want it to look like, so now I just want to split it into separate tables.

Comment: Can I ask why you want to avoid fixed widths? Is it to allow for unknown widths, letting the browser calc for you?

Comment: Yes, mostly.  I personally hate fixed-width pages.  They are always too small or too big for the size I want to run my browser at.  As a user, I know what size I want my browser to be and I hate that web sites think they know better.  As a result, I refrain from making web pages that are fixed-width.

Answer (score 0):

You could just specify the width to be a % of the total page width in the CSS. Assign the same class to the first column in all the tables and set `width: 15%;` This isn't ideal however as the layout will vary based on a client's resolution. You're better off using a fixed width with `position: fixed;`

see [CSS class position](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)

Comment: What do you mean "the layout will vary"?  Setting the width based on percentage of the page width is ok, but I can't accommodate for word-wrapping like the browser can.

Comment: I meant that the objects in a given section/column of the page might not line up properly depending on the browser window size and/or client's resolution.

Alternatively you could set a fixed width for each element along with `margin: 0 auto;` to let the browser automatically calculate just the margin. This is common practice for a wrapper. [See this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275410/correct-way-to-do-a-css-wrapper)

Comment: What happens if the sum of the widths is more than the browser window?  or if the width is smaller than the element using the browser's default font size?  I guess I'll try it and see.

Comment: Sometimes compromises have to be made. There are standard practices that function properly in the vast majority of cases (you can't always satisfy everyone) such as the [960 grid system](http://960.gs/) and [Twitter's Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)

Comment: Bootstrap looks pretty cool.  I might use that for future projects.