# Prevent copy-paste of text. user-select:none doesn't work on Android/iOS when drag across the text

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, ios

How can I make it such that specific text on a webpage cannot be copied by the user?

I've seen all the answers that say to use *user-select:none*. This works on my PC, but not on iOS or Android. (Tried Chrome and Safari.) The text gets copied if you start the selection on the selectable text and drag down below the non-selectable text. It doesn't look like the text was selected, but if you copy and paste it, you'll see it.

My question is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27007947/how-to-prevent-user-copying-text-of-a-certain-div-using-css), but that question is 9 years old and doesn't have an answer. I'm hoping there might be some new insight.

```
.nocopy{
    -webkit-touch-callout:none;
    -webkit-user-select:none;
    -khtml-user-select:none;
    -moz-user-select:none;
    -ms-user-select:none;
    user-select:none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

<div>hello</div>
<div class="nocopy">no copy</div>
<div>world</div>
```

I'd be OK with a javascript solution, but it's not clear how that can be implemented. This didn't do anything:

```
<script>
    $('.nocopy').bind('copy paste',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); return false; 
    });
</script>
```

**Why I want this?** My site is optimized for screen readers and I have invisible text to help blind people navigate the site. It doesn't make sense to show these messages when people copy information from the page. (I've simplified the sample HTML here. There are various ways to only show text to a screen reader. I'm not asking about that.)

Update: On Android, the issue seems to be with the "copy" option. If I, instead, choose "Share" and then choose the copy option from the share menu, then it, correctly, does not paste the text.