# Placing image at the top left of the screen in html

Tags: html, css, image, stylesheet

please refer to the image below, I wish to add an image to the extreme left and top of the screen such that the word `process` appears to the right of it.

```
<div class="row">
<!--img src="C:/D DRIVE DATA/databit/ymlsite/images/generic/Logo.png", 
height = 50 width = 50/-->
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Please visit ***[How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)***, ***[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)***  before posting this kind of questions.

Comment: is it possible to post the full code you have right now?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an image to the extreme left and top of the screen by using css.

```
<div class="row">
    <img src="C:/D DRIVE DATA/databit/ymlsite/images/generic/Logo.png", 
     height = 50 width = 50/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
img {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
```

By using this you can align image at left and top of screen.
You can refer this code. https://jsfiddle.net/4p0bLurz/